# Are Function Pointers simulating methods harmful in C?

Tags: c, methods, function-pointers

I know I can use function pointers in C to emulate methods like so:

```
typedef struct a
{
    int x, y;
    int (*add)(int x, int y);
}a;

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int main()
{
    a b = {2, 3, &add};
    printf("%d\n", b.add(b.x, b.y));
    return 0;
}
```

However is this bad form in C? Should I find some other way to do this? If this is bad, what should I be doing instead of this? Obviously when I use it it wouldn't be for trivial functions like in this example.

Comment: This sort of approach is used very frequently in real-world C code.

Comment: Depends on if you had a good reason to have the function pointer or not.  If you are just doing it because you are used to Java or C++, then that's not really a good reason.  Why do you think you need to have "methods"?

Comment: My opinion: it's more useful when you might want to change the pointer at runtime, or if you are using this one struct to represent several different types of addition (crude polymorphism).   If you only ever have the one `&add` assigned to the pointer it'd be simpler to not do this.

Answer (score 2):

It is not bad C; Linux is full of such code

It is not clear if this style buys you anything of a value, thus leaving the answer to personal tastes, aesthetics etc.

But one thing I would like to mention: if you really would like to emulate methods, you have to start with emulating 'this' pointer. That is what methods (or encapsulation in general) are all about — they have access to the internals of the structure.

Thus your code shall be like:

```
typedef struct a
{
    int x, y;
    int (*add)(struct a* this, int x, int y);
} a;
```

and:

```
printf("%d\n", b.add(&b, b.x, b.y));
```

Answer (score -1):

This works well in my gcc 4.4.7, and in linux kernel source code, there are many circumstances written in this way. Like file_operations, inode_operations, etc. It is combined with strategy pattern and some object-oriented programming thoughts.
So, I think it is not bad form in C, the only flaw I think is that you can write it like this:

```
a b = {.x=2, .y=3, .add=add};
```

This is more readable and c style.

Comment: It is called a [**designated initializer**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) and it does exactly what the OP was already doing. It does not answer the question **Should I do it?** in any way. If you want to post something like this use **add a comment**